# MS CRON expression for Azure Function

Tags: azure, function, timer, cron, god

I need a CRON expression, compatible with Azure Functions V2, to express such intervals:

- every 30 minutes from 8:30 to 18:30 (including 8:30 and 18:30)
- every 5 minutes from 7:00 to 7:45 (including 7:00 and 7:45)

Is there a way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

***You can use the below CRON expressions to achieve your requirement:***

> 1. every 30 minutes from 8:30 to 18:30 (including 8:30 and 18:30)

`30/30 8-18 * * *`

This CRON expression helps to trigger the function at every 30th minute from 30 mins past the hour between 8 and 18(i.e., 8:30 to 18:30).

[image]

> 2. Every 5 minutes from 7:00 to 7:45 (including 7:00 and 7:45):

`*/5 7 * * *`

This expression helps to trigger the function at every 5th minute between 7 and 7:59(that includes 7:45).

[image]

***You can verify these expressions at [Online CRON Expression Generator](https://crontabkit.com/crontab-expression-generator).***

Comment: Hello! The proposed expressions do not work as expected since:

- The cron [ 0 30/30 8-18 * * * ] only executes at 30 minutes past the hour but not 0 minutes past the hour. It was expected to run at [ 8:30, 9:00, 9:30 ... 18:30 ] but it only runs at [ 8:30, 9:30 ... 18:30 ].

- The cron [ * */5 7 * * * ] runs at 7:50 and 7:55 too (they had to be excluded) but I solved the problem with the cron [ * 5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45 7 * * * ]